# Optional line breaks in rails partial when variable is optional

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some rails partials like:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:div, child) do %>
    <%= child.var1 %><br>
    <%= child.var2 unless child.var2.blank? %><br>
    <%= "Some string" if child.is_stringy? %>
<% end %>
```

that are rendered like so:

```
<%= render @object.children %>
```

How do I make the second and third line breaks be optional without having to wrap the entire block around an if/unless-then-end, like so:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:div, child) do %>
    <%= child.var1 %><br>
    <% unless child.var2.blank? then %>
      <%= child.var2 %><br>
    <% end %>
    <% if child.is_stringy? then %>
      <%= "Some string" if child.is_stringy? %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I really like using the if/unless inline, for brevity and conciseness. I can do something like this:

```
<%= child.var2 + tag(:br) unless child.var2.blank? %>
```

But then I have to fix the escaped tag, like so:

```
<%= raw(child.var2 + tag(:br)) unless child.var2.blank? %>
```

Which works, but makes me a bit uneasy about allowing arbitrary HTML through var2. Any suggestions?

Comment: With [Haml](http://haml.info/) or  [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) you can write less.

Comment: Just as a side note, the `then` keyword is not necessary anywhere in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself doing this often, you could always define a view helper. Something like this:

```
def break_after(value)
  return unless value.present?
  capture do
    concat value
    concat tag(:br)
  end
end
```

And then...

```
<%= break_after child.var1 %>
```

Comment: Great, I ended up writing it to be a bit more flexible and taking a condition parameter, but the general idea is the same.